# Are a lot of people deleting their own accounts, are are we banning them

Tags: discussion

About every other week I see negative points against some old question of mine because someone's account has been deleted.  This makes me kind of worry about what is going on.  What are the reasons someone's account might disappear.

(I know that trying to delete one's own account can be almost impossible, since I have gone through the whole process and still did not manage to delete this one.  So I find it difficult to believe this is happening by choice.)

Can anyone supply some context.

Comment: I can't find how many people are deleting their account right now, but we haven't removed any account recently. Nor have we banned anyone (and I think banning would not have this effect).

Comment: ah yeah i deleted my account a few time. in fact, i'll do so again. everyone misunderstands me :-(

Comment: @user28660 Its ok I feel you